# IE 11 - image stays browser memory, after destroying view

Tags: angularjs

I have image memory leak problem.

I have directive in ng-repeat

```
<div class="add-to-drawer" ng-switch="::listCtrl.isEstateInDrawer(offer.id)" ng-click="listCtrl.toggleOfferFavourites($event, offer, offer.title)">
                  <img class="no-animate" ng-switch-when="true" src="images/icon_favourite_full.png" />
                  <img class="no-animate" ng-switch-when="false" src="images/icon_favourite_empty.png" />
                </div>
```

After switching to another view, taking snapshot in memory I have a lot of weird image objects.

[image: Internet explorer memory snapshot.]

And IE doesn't seem to remove it.

How can I tell IE to remove those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow.
I've analysed snapshots, and google analitycs GTM, was causing memory leaks. Removing GTM helped.